# Use System.runAs() in a Test Method for calling web service

Tags: unit-test, webservices, profile, callout, user

Everytime I solve a problem, another appears. More than a problem, I would say a SalesForce restrictions.

So, I want to test some code (which makes a web service call in order to display some data) with different user profiles. In order to accomplish that, I'm using the System.runAs(User) method.

**First problem** was that it's mandatory to use this method within a test method.

Solved that, easy. I've included the code in a TestMethod.

**Now the second problem** is, within a TestMethod is not possible to make a web service callout.

**¿Which are my options here??!!**

Comment: See [Testing HTTP Callouts](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm) and [Testing Web Service Callouts](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Here is part of a test that makes use of a class that implements `HttpCalloutMock` to return responses that cause various parts of controller logic (where the controller includes a callout) to execute. The mock can also assert that it was passed the correct data in the request.

```
@isTest
private class FacebookCallbackControllerTest {
    private static final String IDENTITY = 'abc123@def456.com';
    private class FacebookMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            if (req.getMethod() == 'POST') {
                // Assume call is to get access token
                HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                res.setBody('access_token=FakeAccessToken');
                res.setStatusCode(200);
                return res;
            } else if (req.getEndpoint().contains('access_token')) {
                // Assume call is to get email
                HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.setBody('{"email":"' + IDENTITY + '"}');
                res.setStatusCode(200);
                return res;
            } else {
                System.assert(false, 'unexpected endpoint=' + req.getEndpoint());
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    @isTest
    static void testEmail() {
        ...
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new FacebookMock());
        Test.startTest();
        FacebookCallbackController controller = new FacebookCallbackController();
        PageReference nextPr = controller.init();
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(IDENTITY, nextPr.getParameters().get('email'));
        ...
    }
}
```

As commented earlier, some documentation links on mocks are:

- [Testing HTTP Callouts](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm) for explicit (usually REST) GET/POST requests
- [Testing Web Service Callouts](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) for apex2wsdl generated SOAP code

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can test the actual web service from your apex test class.  But you can test the apex around the callout by wrapping the callout:

```
if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
    callout();
}
```

Comment: Better to use mocking - see the links in the comment on the question.

Comment: Agreed.  Mocking  is the ideal solution.

Comment: This should be done only when there is very complex response and it is not possible to create a mock for that. For simple web services, we should use HttpCalloutMock only.